# List comprehension with averages

Tags: python, string, list, dictionary, average

I have a string, dictionary in the form:

```
('The puppy likes flowers',
 {'laughter': (8.5, 0.9313),
  'flowers': (7.88, 1.1718),
  'the': (4.98, 0.9145),
  'puppy': (7.58, 1.4581),
  'died': (1.56, 1.198),
  'laugh': (9.5, 0.1),
  'flow': (2.3, 0.51),
  'likes':(5.9, 0.032),
  'like':(6.5, 0.021)    
   }
  )
```

Each parentheses is a tuple which corresponds to (score, standard deviation). I'm taking the average of just the first integer in each tuple. I've tried this:

```
def score(string, d):
    if len(string) == 0:
        return 0
    string = string.lower()
    included = [d[word][0]for word in d if word in string]
    return sum(included) / len(included)
```

When I run:

```
print score ('The puppy likes flower', {'laughter': (8.5, 0.9313), 'flower': 
(7.88, 1.1718), 'the':(4.98, 0.9145), 'puppy':(7.58, 1.4581), 
'died':(1.56, 1.198),'laugh': (9.5, 0.1),'flow': (2.3, 0.51)})
```

I should get the average of only `'the'`, `'puppy',` `'likes'` and `'flowers'`: `4.98 + 7.88 + 5.9 + 7.58 / 4` but this running function also includes `'like'` and `'flow'` : `4.98 + 7.88 + 5.9 + + 7.58 + 6.5 + 2.3 / 6`.

Comment: A few points to clarify for your question [1] you have a tuple, [2] `string` is a bad name for a variable (its the name of a built-in) and [3] `if len(string) == 0:` can be simplified to `if not len(string):`

Comment: You don't even have to check the length. Python does that for you, simply use if not string: return None

Comment: Similar post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13006271/using-list-comprehension

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off using the variable string is not a great idea ... but its OK here ... you have a flaw in the logic ... the following works

```
def avg(l):
    if l:
        return sum(l)/len(l)
    return 0

def score(s, d):
    return avg([d.get(x,[0])[0] for x in s.lower().split()])
```

This will add a 0 for pieces of the string `s` that are not in `d` ... if you wanted to ignore them use the following instead

```
def score(s, d):
    return avg([d[x][0] for x in s.lower().split() if x in d])
```

Comment: What if x is not in the dictionary?

Comment: There fixed if x is not in d.

Comment: Interesting way to fix it. Good.

Comment: Actually that adds a zero in the average which maybe wrong but the requirements did not talk about that case

Comment: I know. That's why I said interesting. I don't think it creates any issues, though.

Comment: If the requirements are that the average of only pieces in the dict and nothing outside ... I have added it to my answer

Answer (score 0):

You should split the string first:

```
splited_string = string.split()
included = [d[word][0]for word in d if word in splited_string]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get this part in the function below, but I decided to clean your tuple a bit:

```
tuple = ('The puppy likes flowers',
 {'laughter': (8.5, 0.9313),
  'flowers': (7.88, 1.1718),
  'the': (4.98, 0.9145),
  'puppy': (7.58, 1.4581),
  'died': (1.56, 1.198),
  'laugh': (9.5, 0.1),
  'flow': (2.3, 0.51),
  'likes':(5.9, 0.032),
  'like':(6.5, 0.021)    
   }
  )

string = tuple[0]
dict = tuple[1]
```

Now defining our function:

```
def score(string, dict):
    s = 0
    n = 0
    for each in string.lower().split(' '):
       if each in dict.keys():
          s += dict[each][0]
          n += 1
    average = s/n
    return average
```

In your case:

```
In [43]: string
Out[43]: 'The puppy likes flowers'

In [44]: dict
Out[44]: 
{'died': (1.56, 1.198),
 'flow': (2.3, 0.51),
 'flowers': (7.88, 1.1718),
 'laugh': (9.5, 0.1),
 'laughter': (8.5, 0.9313),
 'like': (6.5, 0.021),
 'likes': (5.9, 0.032),
 'puppy': (7.58, 1.4581),
 'the': (4.98, 0.9145)}
```

Evaluating the function:

```
In [45]: score(string, dict)
Out[45]: 6.585
```

Comment: Wow see the note at the top of my answer ... you are super overriding python builtin variables/types

Comment: I didn't want to change all the variables so it would be easy to understand to OP however you're right, it needs to have other variable names. By the way, the addition of tuple and dict was intended to be humorous.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using python's 'in' operation try to use ==
That is,
Edited:

```
string = string.split(' ') #Returns a list of word

included = [d[word][0]for word in d if word == string]
```

Comment: The word is part of the string not the whole thing

Comment: Also *in* wouldn't work either since it will allow partial matches.

Comment: Thanks for noticing it...I totally forgot to split the string :)

Answer (score 0):

Like the other answers so far, this answer looks up in the dictionary the scores for words split from the input string, which is different than what your example code does, which is to find dictionary words as parts of the input string and add up their scores.  Also, the logic of this answer is similar to that of some of the other answers, but is expressed more compactly by using python's built-in `filter` function.  The output of the program shown below is `6.585`, `6.15333333333`, `None`, `6.032` on four lines.

```
w={'puppy': (7.58, 1.4581), 'likes': (5.9, 0.032), 'laugh': (9.5, 0.1), 'flow': (2.3, 0.51), 'the': (4.98, 0.9145), 'flowers': (7.88, 1.1718), 'laughter': (8.5, 0.9313), 'died': (1.56, 1.198), 'like': (6.5, 0.021)}

def score(s, d):
    v = [d[a][0] for a in filter(lambda x: x in d, s.lower().split())]
    return sum(v)/len(v) if len(v) else None

print score('the puppy likes flowers', w)
print score('the puppy likes flower', w)
print score('short stuff', w)
print score('the flowers flow like laughter', w)
```